# XNA RenderTarget Preserve Contents

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm trying to load a texture into a rendertarget once on the first draw and then preserve the contents to draw the same texture every frame without recreating it.

This is the code I have but it doesnt work and only shows the empty texture area and

```
RenderTarget2D rTarget = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(GameBackgroundColor);

            SpriteBatch.Begin();

            if (rTarget == null)
            {
                rTarget = new RenderTarget2D(Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice,
                                           Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
                                           Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
                                           false,
                                           Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat,
                                           DepthFormat.Depth24, 0, RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents);

                Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rTarget);

                Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

                Game.SpriteBatch.Draw(ContentManager.Load<Texture2D>("tiles"), new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), Color.White);

                Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
            }

            SpriteBatch.Draw(rTarget, new Rectangle(0, 0,400, 400), Color.White);

            //draw the character
            character.Draw(gameTime);

            SpriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

And this is the end result:
[image: failed to render texture correctly]

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot about `Game.SpriteBatch.Begin()` and `End()` for render target. Also I think you should move `SpriteBatch.End()` close to `Draw(rTarget...` method call (especially if `Game.SpriteBatch` and `SpriteBatch` is the same variable).

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(GameBackgroundColor);
if (rTarget == null)
{
    rTarget = new RenderTarget2D(Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice,
        Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
        Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
        false,
        Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat,
        DepthFormat.Depth24, 0, RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents);

    Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rTarget);
    Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

    Game.SpriteBatch.Begin();
    Game.SpriteBatch.Draw(ContentManager.Load<Texture2D>("tiles"), new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), Color.White);
    Game.SpriteBatch.End();
    Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
}

SpriteBatch.Begin();
SpriteBatch.Draw(rTarget, new Rectangle(0, 0,400, 400), Color.White);

//draw the character
character.Draw(gameTime);

SpriteBatch.End();

base.Draw(gameTime);
```

Comment: Yep, just managed to figure it out, thanks for the answer tho :) you were correct.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - turns out you need SpriteBatch.Begin and SpriteBatch.End around each draw onto a render target.

```
RenderTarget2D rTarget = null;
/// <summary>
/// This is called when the game should draw itself.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{

    if (rTarget == null)
    {
        rTarget = new RenderTarget2D(Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice,
                                        Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
                                        Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
                                        false,
                                        Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat,
                                        DepthFormat.Depth24, 0, RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents);

        Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rTarget);

        Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        SpriteBatch.Begin(); //new

        Game.SpriteBatch.Draw(ContentManager.Load<Texture2D>("tiles"), new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), Color.White);

        SpriteBatch.End(); //new

        Game.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
    }

    GraphicsDevice.Clear(GameBackgroundColor);

    SpriteBatch.Begin();

    SpriteBatch.Draw(rTarget, new Rectangle(0, 0,400, 400), Color.White);

    //draw the character
    character.Draw(gameTime);

    SpriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```